# is that possible to do igblast(Analyze immunoglobulin (Ig) sequences) with python/biopython

Tags: biopython, blast

I'm fresh to python/biopython and tried blast using biopython like this:

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW
    fasta_string = open("C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\xxxx\\abc.fasta").read()
    result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "nr", fasta_string)
    print result_handle.read()
```

I was wondering if it is possible to run [igblast](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/igblast/) using biopython. I have searched for this but it seems no one is really doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried them, but I have found:

1. [pyigblast](https://github.com/andrejbranch/pyigblast).

> PyIgBlast - Open source Parser to call IgBlast and parse results for
>   high-throughput sequencing. Uses Python multi-processing to get around
>   bottlenecks of IgBlast multi-threading. Parses blast output to
>   deliminated files (csv,json) for uploading to databases. Can connect
>   directly with mysql and mongo instances to insert directly.

The code uses Python 2.7 and BioPython.

2. [PyIR](https://github.com/crowelab/PyIR)

> Immunoglobulin and T-Cell receptor rearrangement software. A Python wrapper for IgBLAST that scales to allow for the parallel processing of millions of reads on shared memory computers. All output is stored in a convenient JSON format.

The code uses Python 3.6 and BioPython.

Both tools use a locally installed `igblastn`  executable. You can install `igblastn` locally with [`conda install igblast`](https://bioconda.github.io/recipes/igblast/README.html).